# How can I write to a placeholder the text from an elementByid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, getelementbyid

How can I write to a placeholder the text from an elementByid?

The text in the relevant id:

```
function friendMessage(jqEvent){
          $('#labelTo').text(jqEvent.attr('friendName'));
}
```

The placeholder:

```
 <input type="text"  name="to" class="required char-countable1 msg" maxlength="250"  placeholder="To: " >
```

***the text should display after the To***

Answer (score 0):

You can update the placeholder to append the text of the label like this.

```js
function friendMessage(jqEvent){
    var input = $('input.required.char-countable1.msg');
    input.attr('placeholder', input.attr('placeholder') + $('#labelTo').text());
}
               
friendMessage();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="labelTo">test value</label>
<input class="required char-countable1 msg" placeholder="To: "/>
```